# Doppler shift of light from stars and galaxies

Tags: cosmology, visible-light, doppler-effect, redshift

I was reading about how we can ascertain whether a cosmic object is receding from or approaching us by studying the doppler shift of its spectrum- I mean the redshift and blue-shift.

But we have no idea about the actual frequency of light emitted by the cosmic object. Then how can we say that the light is getting red-shifted or blue-shifted?

Some texts suggest that the frequency of the emitted radiation depends on the hydrogen, helium, lithium, carbon etc. content of the cosmic object. But we can at most make a guess about its percentage composition. Then how can we identify what the frequency of the emitted radiation is?

And, if the above mentioned way is not how we understand the doppler shift of the light emitted by cosmic objects, how do we confirm that the light is getting doppler shifted?

**EDIT**:

My question is almost similar to the duplicate question. It has solved my problem to a good extent but it doesn't totally resolve my problem.

Say we are receiving a pattern of lines from a particular star and the lines are characteristic of an element $X_1$. What happens if the red-shifted line pattern of $X_1$ resembles the pattern of lines for some other distinct element $X_2$?

How do we understand if the star is emitting light characteristic of the element $X_1$ or $X_2$?

If the question still looks unclear, you can refer to the comments section where I have tried to elaborate my query to John Rennie.

Comment: See the question I've linked above. Elements have characteristic patterns of absorption lines, and we look for those patterns and measure how much the whole pattern has shifted.

Comment: @JohnRennie The link was good and it helped. But One thing still bugs me. Say we have a pattern of lines of wavelengths $\lambda_1\pm \delta \lambda$ which is mainly red in colour and characteristic of some element $X_1$. So how do we realise if that is the actual frequency of light emitted by the star or the doppler shift of the pattern of lines characteristic of some other element $X_2$?

Comment: The pattern of absorption lines from an element is usually very complex with dozens or hundreds of lines, and there is no chance of accidentally mistaking it for the pattern from a different element.

Comment: @JohnRennie No, you got me wrong. I wanted to ask, say we are seeing a red light. How do we know that the star is emitting some light, characteristic of some element $X_1$, which is getting red-shifted and NOT that the star is emitting that red light only, characteristic of some other element $X_2$?

Comment: Because the patterns of the lines for $X_1$ and $X_2$ are different. Admittedly if we only see one line then we can't tell what element produced it, but solar spectra contain thousands of lines so we can look at the positions of many lines.

Comment: @JohnRennie Sorry that I am failing to make my point clear. I agree that the pattern of lines for $X_1$ and $X_2$ are different. But it may so happen that the red-shifted line pattern of $X_1$ resembles the pattern of lines for $X_2$. What then? This is what I am trying to ask.

Comment: For the common elements there is no way to shift the patterns to make one element look like another because the patterns of the lines are just too different. For example if you took the oxygen absorption lines you couldn't shift the spectrum around to make it look like the carbon spectrum. There's isn't a chunk of the oxygen spectrum that looks just like a chunk of the carbon spectrum only shifted in frequency.

Comment: Well, that's true if you can see a reasonable number of lines. If you could see only two lines then I'm sure there will be spacings between two lines that are similar in different spectra, but you wouldn't base a red shift measurement of just two lines.

Comment: This question appear to have an ulterior motive. *Obviously* if there is a pattern of lines at one redshift due to some combination of elemental absorption/emission that is *perfectly* mimicked by another set of elements at a different redshift, then there is no way to distinguish them (other than by getting more data at other wavelengths). In practice, the only confusion that ever occurs is if only one or two prominent lines are seen in poor spectrum of a very distant galaxy.